Vuetify error findComponentParent prevents my app to load correctly
After upgrading my project, I run into the following error with vuetify@3.7.2.
It completely prevents my app from loading correctly but I would say it's hard to debug. I've tried to rollback Vuetify alone but it didn't solve the issue.
Other packages might be linked including vite-plugin-vuetify@2.0.4.
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not find original vnode
    at findComponentParent (directiveComponent.mjs?v=8cc27c4b:60:11)
    at directiveComponent.mjs?v=8cc27c4b:26:58
    at callWithErrorHandling (chunk-2F7H6EIX.js?v=8cc27c4b:2532:19)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (chunk-2F7H6EIX.js?v=8cc27c4b:2539:17)
    at invokeDirectiveHook (chunk-2F7H6EIX.js?v=8cc27c4b:3049:7)
    at chunk-2F7H6EIX.js?v=8cc27c4b:6157:17
    at flushPostFlushCbs (chunk-2F7H6EIX.js?v=8cc27c4b:2710:28)
    at flushJobs (chunk-2F7H6EIX.js?v=8cc27c4b:2753:5)


You should be able to rollback it if lock file is under version control. It's impossible to answer your question, it's specific to your case, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please, provide a way to reproduce. Without other details, this requires to debug in a straightforward way, to figure out why this error occurs https://unpkg.com/browse/vuetify@3.5.16/lib/composables/directiveComponent.mjs and what happens internally

Have you done the npm routine, i.e. delete lock file and install again, delete node_modules and install again?

I could test it and its coming from ugrading to vuetify@3.7.0, didn't pinpoint the problem yet
